# Does RestTemplate synchronize REST calls?

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest

I am curious of one thing about RestTemplate. Let's say I have an ordinary Spring singleton component bean `RestService` with dummy method:

```
@Component
public class RestService {
   private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

   public String performRequest(HttpEntity request, URI url) {
      return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
   }
}
```

Now thread `thread-1` interacts with this bean and waits for rest response. Does it mean that any other thread that eager to make another request through this bean will be stuck until the `thread-1` releases the `restTemplate`? I tried to present the flow on the figures below.

```
thread-1 ..request....execution..................response..
thread-N ---------request.......wait..............start execution...
```

or

```
thread-1 ..request....execution..................response..
thread-N ---------request.......execution....response...
```

In other words. Is it ok to use such service with `restTemplate` with multi-threading calls and does it work like fig. 1 or fig. 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RestTemplate` is thread-safe (with a disclaimer), so you can share one between multiple users just like you've done in your code. They don't need to wait for each other, in fact they don't even have any idea if there are other requests being executed at the same time.

The javadoc for the class doesn't describe it being thread-safe, but the code uses only local variables so there's no shared state to compete for.

Disclaimer: it's not entirely free of shared state, because you can configure some things like `setMessageConverters()`, `setErrorHandler()` etc. but those should be configured once only. The actual methods that do network things are thread-safe.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! This is exactly what I wanted to know.